# Why aren't my sent messages from iPad and iPhone syncing?

Tags: iphone, messages, ipad

I sent someone a message from my iPad through iMessage and I know that my devices always syncronise my iMessage stuff, so it should have popped up on my iPhone that I sent the message (as both were beside me). However, it didn't pop up on my iPhone - there's no evidence of me ever sending the message - but it's still on as *Delivered* on my iPad.

Has the message been received or was it glitched and never got to the recipient?

Answer (score 1):

When you send a message from iPhone Messages app, all your messages are texts, but not all your texts are SMS.

Comment: To be correct, SMS never will be iMessage nor will SMS be iMessages. iMessages are sent via Apple's services and SMS are sent via your provider.